# test CLGeocoder geocodeAddressString method placemarks is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, clgeocoder

Codes are from book , It's always failed in the first XCTFail(), I tried it on both device and simulator, It should't be network issue, look into the error, it shows `Optional(Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)")`

```
func test_GeocoderWorksAsExpected() {
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Wait for geocode")
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString("Infinite Loop 1, Cupertino") {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        let placemark = placemarks?.first

        let coordinate = placemark?.location?.coordinate
        guard let latitude = coordinate?.latitude else {
            XCTFail(); return
        }
        guard let longitude = coordinate?.longitude else {
            XCTFail(); return
        }
        XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(latitude, 37.3316851, accuracy: 0.000001)
        XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(longitude, -122.0300674, accuracy: 0.000001)

        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(3, handler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say it shouldn't be a network error, but that's precisely what a `CLErrorDomain` error with a code of 2 is (`CLError.Network`). You can get that for a variety of reasons. For example, I got it when I tried monitoring the communication with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com), but hadn't yet told my computer to trust the Charles certificate. But once I did, that error went away. You might want to confirm that you're not using a proxy server or other networking that interferes with TLS/HTTPS requests.

As an aside, I'd also suggest:

- You should `defer` the fulfillment of the expectation (so it gets fulfilled regardless of what path you take out of that closure); and
- You might want to reduce the accuracy of that latitude and longitude error check (as I found my results differed ever so slightly).

So, perhaps something like:

```
func testGeocoder() {
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Wait for geocode")
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString("Infinite Loop 1, Cupertino") { placemarks, error in
        defer { expectation.fulfill() }

        guard error == nil else {
            XCTFail(error!.localizedDescription); return
        }

        guard let coordinate = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate else {
            XCTFail("No coordinate"); return
        }

        XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(coordinate.latitude, 37.3316851, accuracy: 0.001, "Latitude doesn't match")
        XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(coordinate.longitude, -122.0300674, accuracy: 0.001, "Longitude doesn't match")
    }
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(3, handler: nil)
}
```

Comment: I would say it's a network issue beyond my ability, I accidently dicide to replace the address filled in code with my home address and it works. Thanks for your answer, I really learned something from the code you provided : )